# How do I fix a bad Capistrano deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

Made a large update last night and my site is currently down. I used `cap deploy:rollback` with no luck. The error logs aren't telling me much. The last error I saw when trying to deploy was:

```
 ** [out :: website.com] You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
 ** [out :: website.com] your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
 ** [out :: website.com] updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
 ** [out :: website.com] 
 ** [out :: website.com] You have deleted from the Gemfile:
 ** [out :: website.com] * asset_sync
    command finished in 934ms
```

My `cap tail` just says the following with no errors:

```
Migrating to AddSessionsTable (20120722094547)
Migrating to AddSlugToUserProjects (20120723204816)
Migrating to AddSlugIndexToUserProjects (20120723205558)
Migrating to CreateFriendlyIdSlugs (20120723210904)
Migrating to AddNameToUsers (20120723221700)
Migrating to AddSlugToUsers (20120723222456)
Migrating to CreateComments (20120724203252)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Gemfile change didn't go well. How it was fixed:

1. logged into server, there were 6 ruby processes that were taking all available things. This is almost certainly the unicorn processes trying to start and couldn't… `killall -9 ruby`
2. cd into the app's current directory
3. RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
4. service unicorn_whimseybox start

It looks like (in the unicorn.log), the error was:
E, [2012-07-26T17:27:10.552912 #24818] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant AssetSync (NameError)

Answer (score 0):

Run `bundle install` on your development server, then `cap deploy`. Another possible solution: add `asset_sync` back to your Gemfile.

As last resort, you can run `cap -d deploy`. It will run deployment step-by-step, asking you for continue on each step. Login to production server in separate shell and do some adjustments between steps manually.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error after converting some Gemfile `source` lines into blocks.

The error was due an old Bundler version on production (1.7.3) vs 1.8.3 on development.